# window.location.href for SMS messaging - Platform compatability

Tags: javascript, cordova, sms

I am using the following command in Javascript to send SMS messages.

```
window.location.href = "sms:[phone number goes here]?body=" + "hello test message";
```

I am developing my app using cordova 3.0 + Icenium. Is this command will launch the SMS client on all smartphones? -- If not, which mobile platforms are compatible with this command?

I currently tested it on my HTC Nexus One Android device and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.open ("sms:[phone number goes here]?body=" + "hello test message","_system");
```

Comment: Change `?body=` to `&body=`. Should work on all iOS > 7

Answer (score 2):

Use this it will work on iOS

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var url;

if (ua.indexOf("iphone") > -1 || ua.indexOf("ipad") > -1)
    url = "sms:;body=test";
else
    url = "sms:?body=test";

//window.location.href = url;
 window.open (url);
```